# Средство связи или нет?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения](22)Я ненавидел их ужасно, хотя, пожалуй, был их же хуже. (23)Они мне тем же платили и не скрывали своего ко мне омерзения
Разве "тем" не является личным местоимением, которое связано слова друг с другом?
Сам текст:

> (18)Чин почитали за ум; в шестнадцать лет уже толковали о теплых
> местечках. (19)Конечно, много тут было от глупости, от дурного
> примера, беспрерывно окружавшего их детство и отрочество.
> (20)Развратны они были до уродливости. (21)Разумеется, и тут было
> больше внешности, больше напускной циничности; разумеется, юность и
> некоторая свежесть мелькали и в них даже из-за разврата; но
> непривлекательна была в них даже и свежесть и проявлялась в каком-то
> ёрничестве. (22)Я ненавидел их ужасно, хотя, пожалуй, был их же хуже.
> (23)Они мне тем же платили и не скрывали своего ко мне омерзения.
> (24)Но я уже не желал их любви; напротив, я постоянно жаждал их
> унижения. (25)Чтоб избавить себя от их насмешек, я нарочно начал как
> можно лучше учиться и пробился в число самых первых. (26)Это им
> внушило некоторое почтение. (27)К тому же все они начали помаленьку
> понимать, что я уже читал такие книги, которых они не могли читать, и
> понимал такие вещи (не входившие в состав нашего специального курса),
> о которых они и не слыхивали.

Comment: Замечание по заданному вопросу.  Надо было ясно указать, о каком задании идет речь и привести его точную формулировку.  Это задание https://self-edu.ru/ege2021_rus_36.php?id=8_25  или нет? Там идет речь о личном и указательном местоимении.  В предложении 23 указательное местоимение ТЕМ служит средством связи, но личные местоимения повторяются в обоих предложениях.  Они относятся ко  всей теме, а не только к этим двум предложениям. В ответе на это задание указывается предложение 26, где выполнено оба условия.

Comment: @Sharon Вы о другом задании написали, как я и говорил.

Answer (score 1):

В этом задании надо найти предложения, в которых **указательное и личное** местоимения выступают средством связи с предыдущим предложением. Общая тема текста: противопоставление  **«я и они».**

Рассмотрим **два возможных** ответа:

1. *(22) Я ненавидел их ужасно, хотя, пожалуй, был их же хуже. (23) Они мне **тем же** платили и не скрывали своего ко мне омерзения.*

Сравнить: *Я **ненавидел** их ужасно, они меня **ненавидели** тоже.* Местоимение **«тем»** используется, чтобы избежать **повтора** глагола.

2. Правильный ответ:  *(25) Чтоб избавить себя от **их насмешек**, я нарочно начал как можно лучше учиться и пробился в число самых первых. (26) **Это им** внушило некоторое почтение.*

Здесь местоимение ***"это"*** указывает на  предыдущее **предложение.**  Есть личное местоимение ***«им»***, которого нет в предыдущем предложении (там ***их*** — притяжательное местоимение).

Answer (score 1):

**Да. Вы правы.**

"Тем" - это указательное местоимение, которое относится к предшествующему предложению, так как заменяет собой целую конструкцию - ***они тоже ненавидели меня***. Если бы мы написали прямо, то связь была бы осуществлена с помощью форм слов - **ненавидел и ненавидели**, но в данном случае мы эту мысль умещаем в слово "тем".

***P.S.*** В ответе от составителей этого сборника содержится ошибка. Такое бывает, увы, часто.

Comment: Мы на кафедре обсуждали этот вопрос. Связь есть, и вы к тому же условия задания исказили, там нет личного местоимения, только указательное.

Comment: Спрашивают об этом предложении, а не о 26. 26 тоже подходит, но и здесь связь есть. В задании четко сказано: выберите один или несколько вариантов. Никакого личного местоимения в помине нет в задании. Среди предложений 18-27 найдите такое(-ие), которое(-ые) связано(-ы) с предыдущим при помощи указательного местоимения. Напишите номер(-а) этого(-их) предложения(-ий).

Comment: Автор четко озвучил задание: надо найти указательное местоимение. Это вы искажаете факты, мы давно разобрались.

Comment: @Sharon Поэтому "разве" и написано. Автор считает, что это именно средство связи в данном предложении, и это правильно. А сомнения могли возникнуть потому, что в ответах указан только номер 26. А это ошибка, потому что ответ такой: 2326.